# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, evaluation

I'm very new to doing java and am trying at doing a calculator after reading the basic tutorials. I've been trying to crack this error for some time now, which is how to turn my sum as a string into an epression and evaluate it. 
(to let you know, I have tried .parseInt and engine.eval which resulted in nothing but errors.)

Here is the important bit of code:

```
private JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);    
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        DoubleEvaluator evaluator = new DoubleEvaluator();
        Double result = evaluator.evaluate(txt.getText());
        String x = String.valueOf(result);

        if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText() != "="){
                txt.setText(txt.getText()+((JButton)e.getSource()).getText());}         
        else{
            txt.setText(x);
        }



    }}
```

Please can someone supply me a (simple) answer to my needs.

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked,
Thank youuuuu :)

Rest of code below:

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.fathzer.soft.javaluator.DoubleEvaluator;

public class calculator_gui extends JFrame{
    private JButton



    b1 = new JButton("1"),
    b2 = new JButton("2"),
    b3 = new JButton("3"),
    b4 = new JButton("4"),
    b5 = new JButton("5"),
    b6 = new JButton("6"),
    b7 = new JButton("7"),
    b8 = new JButton("8"),
    b9 = new JButton("9"),
    b0 = new JButton("0"),
    bx = new JButton("*"),
    bp = new JButton("+"),
    bs = new JButton("-"),
    bd = new JButton("/"),
    br = new JButton("=");

private JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);    
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        DoubleEvaluator evaluator = new DoubleEvaluator();
        Double result = evaluator.evaluate(txt.getText());
        String x = String.valueOf(result);

        if(!((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("=")){
                txt.setText(txt.getText()+              ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText());}           
        else{
            txt.setText(x);
        }



    }}
private ButtonListener bl = new ButtonListener();
public calculator_gui(){
    b1.addActionListener(bl);
    b2.addActionListener(bl);
    b3.addActionListener(bl);
    b4.addActionListener(bl);
    b5.addActionListener(bl);
    b6.addActionListener(bl);
    b7.addActionListener(bl);
    b8.addActionListener(bl);
    b9.addActionListener(bl);
    b0.addActionListener(bl);
    bp.addActionListener(bl);
    bs.addActionListener(bl);
    bx.addActionListener(bl);
    br.addActionListener(bl);
    bd.addActionListener(bl);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(txt);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);
    add(b4);
    add(b5);
    add(b6);
    add(b7);
    add(b8);
    add(b9);
    add(bx);
    add(b0);
    add(bd);
    add(bp);
    add(bs);
    add(br);



}
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    //run(new Button(), 240, 180);
    calculator_gui frame = new calculator_gui();
    frame.setTitle("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(160, 210);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

}


}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` and `!=` to compare strings. Use `if(!((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("=")){`

Comment: Please provide what you input in the text field, what is the expected result and the stacktrace thrown. Normally: Integer.parseInt() should work if the string is an integer :)

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: It doesn't label a specific line. The text field will hold an equation, input by JButtons, eg "1*1"